# Does ray tracing render time depend linearly on image resolution?

Tags: 3d

(I'm not quite sure whether this question really belongs on this particular Stack Exchange, but I don't know where else to ask. If people think it's inappropriate for this SE, I'll be happy to move or delete it.)

I'm using a ray tracing program, POV-Ray, to render a 3d scene I've been working on. A low resolution test render already took a long time to complete (about 5 hours), and it'd be nice to have a preliminary estimate for the render time of the final high resolution image. So my question is: **Does the amount of time it takes to render the scene depend linearly on the desired image resolution, all other things (such as field of view and aspect ratio) being equal?** That is, if I increase the resolution from 1 MP to 10 MP, does the render time increase from 5 hours to 50 hours (or thereabouts)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, render time should roughly scale in a linear fashion, with each pixel taking about the same amount of time to render.

There are many other factors that could throw it off though — running short on RAM, setup and post-processing.

The easiest way to find out would be to render a few lower res tests at different resolutions and graph the times against pixel count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own tests, but in this case the "weight" of the final file dosen't say anithing. If you save a bmp file will weight lets say 1mb and the exact same file on png could weight 1/3 of thoose mb.

One thing that can be somehow estimated is the resolution.

The resolution is the "size" in pixels. For example If you have a file 1000 x 1000 px and you want to render a final file double the size, 2000 x 2000 px it will be 4 times bigger. **It is a square proportion**, not a linear one.

But it will be a limit due your phisical ram, and your program could crash after certain limits.

One test I would recomend is to do verey small renders, 200x200px, 400x400px and 600x600px, write the times on an excell table and see the proportion. They should be arround 1x, 4x, 9x.

And you can perform aditional tests like 200x200 with dof, and without it for example and complete your table in aditional columns.

Comment: He is talking about Megapixels which allready accounted for the nonlinearity and just counts pixels so yes his expected behaviour is linear.